# Making one table cell fill the row

Tags: html, css

[demo link](https://playcode.io/586685/)

There is this table with three columns in a row.

The 1st column's contents will always be short enough to be within the width of `140px;`.

The 2nd column can have varying length of contents but I want to make it fill the rest of the row. To put it in another way, I want the third row to be pushed to the very right of a row all the time.

What I've tried and didn't work was wrapping `elem` class with another `div` that is `display:flex`. Short of knowledge, and not every answer on the internet is applicable.

```
<div>
  <div class="edKsT">
    <div @click="beginEdit">

      <div class="esm">

        <div class="elem">
            <label>a</label>
            <div class="second">contents2</div>
            <div class="third">-</div>
        </div>

        <div class="elem">
          <label>b</label>
          <div class="second">contents</div>
          <div class="third">X</div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
.edKsT {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  color : white
}

.edKsT .esm {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.edKsT label {
  display: inline;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.edKsT .esm .elem {
  display: table-row;
}

.edKsT .esm .elem label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 140px;
}

.edKsT .esm .elem div {
  margin: 0.25rem;
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the kind of table you see from this template. thank you..!

```js
// '.tbl-content' consumed little space for vertical scrollbar, scrollbar width depend on browser/os/platfrom. Here calculate the scollbar width .
$(window).on("load resize ", function() {
  var scrollWidth = $('.tbl-content').width() - $('.tbl-content table').width();
  $('.tbl-header').css({'padding-right':scrollWidth});
}).resize();
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}


/* demo styles */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #25c481, #25b7c4);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}


/* follow me template */
.made-with-love {
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
}
.made-with-love i {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #F50057;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
.made-with-love a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.made-with-love a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* for custom scrollbar for webkit browser*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!--for demo wrap-->
  <h1>Fixed Table header</h1>
  <div class="tbl-header">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Change</th>
          <th>Change %</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tbl-content">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAC</td>
          <td>AUSTRALIAN COMPANY </td>
          <td>$1.38</td>
          <td>+2.01</td>
          <td>-0.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAD</td>
          <td>AUSENCO</td>
          <td>$2.38</td>
          <td>-0.01</td>
          <td>-1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAX</td>
          <td>ADELAIDE</td>
          <td>$3.22</td>
          <td>+0.01</td>
          <td>+1.36%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXD</td>
          <td>ADITYA BIRLA</td>
          <td>$1.02</td>
          <td>-1.01</td>
          <td>+2.36%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- follow me template -->
<div class="made-with-love">
  Made with
  <i>♥</i> by
  <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/nikhil8krishnan">Nikhil Krishnan</a>
</div>
```